# What is the best way to compute very large exponents?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, exponential, exponent

I'm new to Python, and I'm trying to solve a programming problem where I have to compute 5 to the n<sup>th</sup> power, and once I have that, I just have to output the last two digits of that number. This is the code I wrote below:

```
print(str(pow(5, int(input())))[-2:])
```

The code works fine, for the most part, but exceeds the 500 ms time limit when the input is a large number like `1000000000000000000`

What is the most efficient way to process such large inputs like this as an exponent without exceeding the time limit?

Comment: `pow(5, n, 100)`.

Comment: Take the first 10 powers of 5. Notice any pattern in the last two digits?

Comment: This problem can be solved by simply listing out the powers of 5 and seeing if there's a pattern. `5**2=25; 5**3 = 125; 5**4 = 625; 5**5=3125` see a pattern?

Comment: Right.  No math is required for this problem.  It's a logic problem.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think it would be that easy, so I didn't try it. I thought I needed to implement some logic or something, but if I can just print(25), I guess that works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It can be shown by induction that 5^n mod 100 = 25, for all n >= 2.  This is clear when n = 2.  Suppose 5^n is of the form 100k+25.  Then 5^(n+1) = 100(5k+1)+25, whence 5^(n+1) mod 100 = 25.  Hence, the last two digits of 5^n is 25, for all n >= 2.

Some general tricks for computing a^n mod b efficiently include repeated squaring for computing a^n, and computing remainders in each step so that the numbers stay small.

Answer (score -1):

For these kinds of heavy calculations you can use Multi Processing to use CPU cores to break down the calculation to little calculation simultaneously.
For example (dummy example) we know 5^4 equals to 625. So we can use 2 cores of CPU to calculate 5^2, then multiply the result. 5^2 * 5^2 = 625.